# Vue3: Uncaught (in promise) Error: Missing required param "c_id"

Tags: typescript, web, vuejs3, tailwind-css, vite

Before I change the path into "edit/:c_id" everything working fine, but after that I got the error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7Atk.png)
Associated block with that change as following:

Route.ts:

```
            {
                path: 'edit/:c_id',
                name: 'cat.edit',
                meta: {notHistory: true},
                component: () => import('@/views/cat/edit.vue')
            }
```

Index.vue(the problem file):

```
<template>
<main class="catIndex">
  <div class="body" v-if="cats">
    <div class="item" v-for="(item,index) in cats" :key="index">
      <el-card shadow="hover">
        <el-image :src="item.preview" :fit="fit" class="rounded"/>
        <div class="title">{{item.title}}</div>
        <div class="buttons">
          <el-button type="success" @click="$router.push({name:'cat.edit',params:{c_id:item.id}})"><icon-editor/>&nbsp;Modify</el-button> // * The problem line
          <el-button type="danger"><icon-delete/>&nbsp;Delete</el-button>
        </div>
      </el-card>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
</template>
```

It's so strange, if the path in Route.ts is 'edit' everything just fine, and I've been reviewed much times, it seems just the problem line associated with that error report. Please help me, I am crazy now.

After trying, I got less but new error as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsSMi.png)

I've "solved" the problem now, I using "query" tag to transmit data instead "params" and it did work as I expected, but I'm still confused about the problem here end up :(

Comment: Looks like the error is in admin.vue file

Comment: Thank you, you are right, and after more attempts, I got new error in "main.ts" ,which is also very confused, and I've already edited that new error as extended.

Comment: Thank you again for your comment, I'm using "query" tag instead "params" to transmit data now and it works for me :)